# Unity - Decreasing float var with "Time.deltaTime" never going down

Tags: unity-game-engine, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm try to create a function to stop player control, but when I pass the duration as a parameter in the function, the variable keeps ina  huge number never really decreasing.

```
public void StopAllPlayerControl(float duration) {

    stopPlayerDuration = duration;

    stopPlayerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;

    //stop here what you need.
    playerInput.enableMovement = false;

    if (stopPlayerDuration <= 0) {

        //restore here to normal state
        playerInput.enableMovement = true;
    }
}
```

And Im calling this funct in a Update method like this

```
StopAllPlayerControl(3);
```

Image here to show that stopPlayerDuration getsm huge but stays in those big numbers never really decreasing. [huge number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKy3.png)

Comment: Well you over and over start a new stop process and always reset the `stopPlayerDuration = duration;` every frame ... so the value will never decrease under `duration - Time.deltaTime` .... Change your logic and either use a Coroutine or set the initial duration only once ...

Answer (score 1):

I used a combination of both answers, organized my logic better and, in this case, I used a coroutine.
This function starts the coroutine and I can call it and control it with a bool

```
public void startStopPlayerCo(float dur) {
    //function to start stop player courutine from anywhere.
    StartCoroutine(StopPlayerCo(dur));
}
```

This is the coroutine that works well now

```
public IEnumerator StopPlayerCo(float dur) {
    
    while (startCO) {
        
        GetComponent<PlayerMove>().enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dur);
        //reset 
        GetComponent<PlayerMove>().enabled = true;
        
        startCO = false;
    }
}
```

And I call it in Update Method like this:

```
startStopPlayerCo(2) //2 seconds, or any var for desired time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float startTime = 0;
float duration = 0;
public void StopAllPlayerControl(float duration) 
{
    this.duration = duration;
    if(playerInput.enableMovement)
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
        playerInput.enableMovement = false;
    }
    if(Time.time - startTime >= this.duration)
    {
        playerInput.enableMovement = true;
    }
}
```

## Explaination

#### Step 1

Firstly, we need to check if movement is already enabled. If it is, we mark the point that we started the timer, and disable movement. We also store our duration in a variable, and reference it locally with the `this` keyword.

```
if(playerInput.enableMovement)
{
    startTime = Time.time;
    playerInput.enableMovement = false;
}
```

#### Step 2

If the timer exceeds the duration then movement is enabled.

```
if(Time.time - startTime < duration)
{
    playerInput.enableMovement = true;
}
```

It is also good practice to enclose this method in a boolean lock to prevent it from being called again while the timer is running, unless you want such a feature to be allowed.

Comment: thank you, the logic in your example I used it for other parts of my project, this time I solved with a courutine.